# CSS Banner image won't appear just plain white background

Tags: css

I have this code in my CSS that only shows plain white image. Who knows how to make it appear?

Result:
[image]

Banner Image:
[image]

```css
/* style.css */

.fixed {
  background-image: url('img/bg.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->

 <div class="fixed">
 <div class="fixed-overlay">
 <div class="landing-text">
  <h1>A lifetime work for "fish"</h1>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean the space needs to be removed?

Comment: try setting the `z-index`, what do you get?

Comment: @ManojKumar the space is where the banner image suppose to be

Comment: Why do you have `display: table`? Try with `block`

Comment: What is the image that you are trying to load? Are you sure it is actually being loaded correctly? Can you see it in the sources tab in devtools?

Comment: @FortyTwo I tried it and it's still the same.

Comment: @JamesCoyle It's a banner image. And the location of the image is in img folder

Answer (score 1):

You're using wrong CSS property.

Instead of `background-image: url('img/bg.png') no-repeat center center fixed;`

Remove keyword `image` in `background-image` and

try this : `background: url('img/bg.png') no-repeat center center fixed;`

Happy Coding ☻

Comment: i've tried that also and same result. Its like the banner image is their but covered in plain white

Comment: can you send me your banner **image url** ?? Cause I'm getting intended result

Comment: I add the banner in description. Please see it.

Comment: Ohh. Now I get that. As you were trying to add background CSS to `<div class=fixed>` but that div does not consist any data or just single line of data so Container is considering it 100% and applying the image to full width of that div which is in fact I guess is not more than 10px. So what you have to do is change height to px ,em,rem i.e. other unit than %.  This might be the solution for your code  [Answer to CSS Banner image won't appear just plain white background](https://codepen.io/mitsukiOrochimaru/pen/bzvPVy)

Answer (score 0):

Try using separate properties

```css
.fixed {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dmnd8.png");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100px;
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
  <div class="fixed-overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still same result

Comment: But the snippet is working fine. Post you full code. There might be some other error

Comment: i tried it making another file and it's working. But not in my index.html

Comment: do the new file and index.html are in the same directory?

Comment: yes, and i called the image also from the same 'img' folder